# In RAD 7.5.4 ,code coverage report

Tags: java

Once the code coverage is enabled in the project properties window . Once the tets case is run or the package it contains of.Junit test case result can be viewed. To generate a code coverage report run -> code coverage -> generate report and will select the test case what we have executed. we can view the report either in HTML view and code coverage report in RAD.

The applciation is of project level and when i try to get code coverage report , whatever package or the test case executed only some packages are been covered and those packages are not no where related to executed test case.

Is it like by default, few packages are considered for coverage ???????

It would be great if someone explains in a better way....